# change default language of wordpress theme

Tags: wordpress

I bought a WordPress theme.
I noticed that the purchased theme contains a language directory (de_DE.po, it_IT.po, ru_RU.po ...)
https://i.stack.imgur.com/vecor.png
 yet I can not change the language of my theme.
I installed the plugin "Loco Translate"
how can I proceed to change the original language of my theme?
thank you.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1FdNV.png)

Answer (score 1):

You can put this code on your wp-config.php:

```
define('WPLANG','');
```

Example :

```
define('WPLANG','de_DE');
```

After that, you go to WP admin in "**Settings**" => "**General**" => "**Site language**" (Choose your language).

I hope this will help you. :)